# how to create a variable from several values

Tags: r

I have a dataset and a subset looks as:

```
          Sample1 Sample2
Weight1   20.5    34.8
Weight2   54.5    23.7
```

I want to create a variable representing all the values like 20.5, 34.8, 54.5, 23.7. I have a bigger dataset and cannot put all the values manually so I want to make a variable representing the values. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want `unlist(df)`? This will return all values as a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described in your questiom, it looks that you are looking for a pivot operation. And from the output that you printed in your question, it looks like your data is currently being interpreted in R, as a matrix. So the first thing I would do, is to transform the data in a data.frame, with `as.data.frame()`, them, I would paste the `row.names()`, to a column like this:

```
data <- as.data.frame(input)

data$Weight <- row.names(data)
```

After that, I would use the `pivot_longer()` function, from `tidyr` package, to get the result (that I think) you want. Like this:

```
library(tidyr)

data <- pivot_longer(
  data,
  cols = -Weight,
  names_to = "Sample",
  values_to = "Value"
)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Weight  Sample  Value
  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 Weight1 Sample1  20.5
2 Weight1 Sample2  34.8
3 Weight2 Sample1  54.5
4 Weight2 Sample2  23.7
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I want this format but I get the numbering for each weight instead of names as I have in original question. I do not have same format for all the weights in my dataset. Is it possible to keep the original names rather than the continuous numbers

Comment: Now maybe I am very confused. But if you just want to extract the names of the Weights in each row of your data, you can do that with: `row.names(data)`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with the previous code that you suggested using pivot_longer. I have a question about the some of the Weight rows that have all zero values across the Samples. How can I drop those rows with all zeros before using pivot so that the data can be manageable.

Comment: If my code worked for you, please check my answer as the correct one. Now, if you want to eliminate some rows that have all zeros, I think is best to filter them after `pivot_longer()`. Because if your data is a matrix, when you filter it, R will return a vector. In other words, you will loose the structure of your data. So after the `pivot_longer()`, try this code: `data <- data[data$Value != 0, ]`